Location Stoppages Time
I am working on live location tracking software.The End users have a motorcycle which they will perform tasks they are assigned to.Based on the mobile coordinates they send to backend server, I am storing them in my database and enriching them in real time.Now,I want to calculate the stoppages if the user has stopped at certain place for more than 5 minutes.How do companies track the timeline i.e stoppages ?
I tried querying the database by grouping the address and finding timestamp difference of when it entered and exited.But what happens is when I revisit the address again,the exit time increases,which will return in increased time difference and the revisit to same place,creates a fake stoppage for that address.Is there a way to discard the fake stoppages ? The same scenario happens if the user is in motion along  a path which has same address name for more than 3 minutes.How do I fix this? Are there any mathematical theories we can apply ,so that we can find user is in motion or not?

The SO community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

why [ if (location@now == location@5minago) then print('stoppage_is_detected') ] doesn't work?

When user stops,due to inaccuracy of GPS,I've observed coordinates jump which results in change in location coordinates so location check won't give accurate result,and moreover due to the huge volume of location data ,won't it increase the processing if we have to do a location check for every 5 minutes ?
